# lock map activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, scroll, locking

In my application im trying to prevet the user to be able to scroll "free" around the map activity , i want the display content to  be lock in some specific coordinates but the difficult part is to concatenate this with the ability of the camera geolocalization(GPS) to follow around the user .

i can for example try to add a move camera to the onLocationChanged and this will lock the camera in the region that i want evry time the user move , but this is not what i want , i just want to reset the camera if the user scroll in a zone that i dont want him to see , if you are browsing the map of Washington i want the camera to reset if the user goes for example on baltimora .

```
 LatLng Washington = new LatLng(38.9150303, -77.1655794);
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            LatLng me = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            //LOCK CAMERA
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Washington));
            //Marker Position
            if (null != currentMarker) {
                currentMarker.remove();
            }
            currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(me).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user to be able to move the map but restrict to a given area, the map offers you that option.

As mentioned here : [Restricting the user's panning to a given area](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views#restricting_the_users_panning_to_a_given_area)

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
// Create a LatLngBounds that includes the city of Adelaide in Australia.
private LatLngBounds ADELAIDE = new LatLngBounds(
  new LatLng(-35.0, 138.58), new LatLng(-34.9, 138.61));
// Constrain the camera target to the Adelaide bounds.
mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(ADELAIDE);
```